# How to add a collapsible button inside Footable table row

Tags: jquery, footable

I am working on a project with strict usability standards.  I know you can collapse an expanded row by clicking on the main table row but I am looking for a way to add a button inside the expanded row that will close it when clicked.

I've tried using jquery to removed the expanded class on click but that doesn't work

```html
<td class="footable-visible" style="display: table-cell;">
  <button>Hide Expanded</button>
  Fair
</td>
```

Here is a pen showing what I am looking for when expanded
[Demo](https://codepen.io/RichCostello/pen/BXBqqO)

Comment: Alon I just fixed that.

Comment: Where is your jQuery? You need to include enough code to reproduce the issue *in the question itself*.